# How do I pass ...array to redis rpush inside Lua script?

Tags: redis, lua, node-redis

I need to iterate ring any times in redis, I have this Lua script:

```lua
local result = redis.call('lrange','test',0,5)
redis.call('ltrim','test',5,-1)
redis.call('rpush','test',result)
return result
```

Here I `lpop` 5 elements, then I need to `rpush` them back.

```
redis.call('rpush','test',result)
```

throws error `Lua redis() command arguments must be strings or integers`, so I need JavaScript like `...result` in Lua.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may use [unpack](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Lua_Programming/Tables#Unpacking_tables) for this.

```
local result = redis.call('lrange','test',0,5)
redis.call('ltrim','test',5,-1)
redis.call('rpush','test',unpack(result))
return result
```

While calling `lrange` you (may) need to use `4` instead of `5` if you want to keep the list size same. Here is the sample demonstration when executing it with `4`.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> rpush test a b c d e f
(integer) 6
127.0.0.1:6379> "EVAL" "local result = redis.call('lrange','test',0,4) redis.call('ltrim','test',5,-1) redis.call('rpush','test',unpack(result)) return result" "0"
1) "a"
2) "b"
3) "c"
4) "d"
5) "e"
127.0.0.1:6379> lrange test 0 -1
1) "f"
2) "a"
3) "b"
4) "c"
5) "d"
6) "e"
```